# How to install ansible to my python at Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, ansible

When I tried to install ansible to my windows PC, stuck with following message.

```
    PS C:\Users\sungyong> pip install ansible
Collecting ansible
  Downloading ansible-2.3.2.0.tar.gz (4.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.3MB 112kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from ansible)
Collecting paramiko (from ansible)
  Downloading paramiko-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (176kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 286kB/s
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6 (from ansible)
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 187kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->ansible)
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.1.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (131kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 228kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from paramiko->ansible)
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading cryptography-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 77kB/s
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading bcrypt-3.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading cffi-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (160kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 122kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 152kB/s
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko->ansible)
  Downloading pycparser-2.18.tar.gz (245kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 147kB/s
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, pynacl, asn1crypto, cryptography, bcrypt, paramiko, pycrypto, ansible
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 81: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
```

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 81: invalid start byte

Is ansible available at windows environment?  If yes, how can I fix this installation problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible is not supported on windows, but you can use a workaround(though not recommended), using Cygwin. [Read about it here](https://ericsysmin.com/2016/07/28/install-ansible-on-windows/).

Comment: This gives a way to do it with a Linux VM running in VirtualBox (see 00:41 to 00:53 from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjighYWw3CQ&index=2&list=PLTgRMOcmRb3MhXTvKSAXNz31L5MWeMA4B)).

Answer (score 0):

use wsl.  On Win10 and higher, just run

```
wsl --install
```

and choose the distro you want.  Then you can install ansible using 'wsl apt', or 'wsl sudo apt'.

From there you can run all the normal ansible commands.  The only tricky thing is when you're at the PS prompt.  If you're using wsl, you need to use Unix separators for full path like:

```
dir C:\Temp
```

becomes

```
wsl ls /mnt/c/temp
```

But the convenience of running powershell and ansible from the same prompt is more than worth it.